# Можно ли восстановить db.sqlite3 на pythonanywhere

Tags: python, django, база-данных, sqlite3, pythonanywhere

Случайно удалил db.sqlite3 на pythonanywhere. Можно ли файл восстановить и как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вернуть базу невозможно, SQLite3 хранит всю информацию про себя в одном единственном файле, это может быть удобно в маленьких портативных программах или в учебных целях, но неприменимо в вебе.